# Why do I see Google ipv4-URL CAPTCHA redirect when I do normal searches?

Tags: google-search

Sometimes when I normally search on Google, a Google CAPTCHA appears on the screen.

The last time I just tried to search "soffione" on Google, it shown me [the following page](https://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect?continue=https://www.google.it/search%3Fq%3Dsoffione%26es_sm%3D119%26biw%3D1872%26bih%3D898%26source%3Dlnms%26sa%3DX%26ei%3DndCeVLySJcHNygOpmYLQDw%26ved%3D0CAUQ_AUoAA%26dpr%3D1&q=CGMSBF0hSJcYoaH7pAUiGQDxp4NLT0w7Kh5B77IZ9U3KTEB43pInd6k); note the `ipv4.google.com` hostname in the URL.

This problem appears also in other computer of my home, and on my Android phone. I don’t understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes malware uses Google to find vulnerable websites and attack them. Google has detected this and asks you now to fill in the Captcha. Make sure to check all your pc's at home for virusses or other malware.